# Material UI Typescript Causing Node OOM in Webpack Dev Server

Tags: typescript, webpack, material-ui, webpack-dev-server

I'm upgrading from material-ui v0.19.1 to v1.0.0-beta.20. Webpack dev server compiles successfully on the boot. However, after the first change, node throws and Out of Memory with the stack trace below. It looks like typescript compilation is causing the error. I tried following the steps on https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14628, but no luck.

```
94% asset optimization
[at-loader] Checking started in a separate process...

<--- Last few GCs --->

  41632 ms: Mark-sweep 1373.4 (1435.0) -> 1373.2 (1435.0) MB, 752.7 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  42331 ms: Mark-sweep 1373.2 (1435.0) -> 1373.2 (1435.0) MB, 698.9 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  43081 ms: Mark-sweep 1373.2 (1435.0) -> 1377.5 (1419.0) MB, 749.8 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
  43802 ms: Mark-sweep 1377.5 (1419.0) -> 1381.9 (1419.0) MB, 720.2 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x2673a12cf781 <JS Object>
   2: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [/Users/name/work/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:24378] [pc=0x3e6e0378c55b] (this=0x2673a1204381 <undefined>,symbol=0x3e7ad43914c1 <a SymbolObject with map 0x2daa61c87129>,id=0x15b6ee481b41 <String[8]: children>)
   3: arguments adaptor frame: 3->2
   4: forEach [native collection.js:~335] [pc=0x3e6e03767052] (this=...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
4: v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::AllocationSite> v8::internal::Factory::New<v8::internal::AllocationSite>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [/usr/local/bin/node]
5: v8::internal::Factory::NewAllocationSite() [/usr/local/bin/node]
6: v8::internal::AllocationSiteCreationContext::EnterNewScope() [/usr/local/bin/node]
7: v8::internal::CreateArrayLiteralImpl(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::LiteralsArray>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FixedArray>, int) [/usr/local/bin/node]
8: v8::internal::Runtime_CreateArrayLiteralStubBailout(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
9: 0x3e6e029079a7
10: 0x3e6e0292be25
error Command failed with signal "SIGABRT".
```

It looks like the issue is caused by typescript. I've tried us

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that I was using `awesome-typescript-loader` instead of the official `ts-loader`. `ts-loader` had already encountered and fixed the problem (which I think has to do with complex generics). Switching to `ts-loader` solved the issue.

Comment: Consider disabling type checking in your loader all together, instead running it via the command line or from your IDE